# How do I upload a new font to use with the Gnome Tweaks tool?

Tags: gnome, fonts, gnome-tweaks

Using the Gnome Tweaks tool, I can choose from a list of pre-downloaded fonts but I do not know how to add a new one. I have downloaded a font, specifically Renogare from https://www.dafont.com/renogare.font, but I don't know how to use it. For themes and icons with the tool, I just added the files to the respective `~/.` folder (such as `~/.themes`), but I can not find a `~/.fonts` or similar folder. Is this something that is possible, and if so how do I do it?

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product/release you're using, but a standard Ubuntu install has multiple font directories; the system font directory has fonts available for all user accounts on the system (*default install puts the fonts here, so any user you've added to your system can use them*), but users can also create their own font directory (*this can be useful for your backup strategy, or non-destructively re-installing your system as system directories will get erased in the type of install I'm using here as example*).